# Using return in shorthand if statement doesn't work

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return

I can't seem to understand why does this work:

```
if(n < i)
{
    functoin();
}
else
{
    return;
}
```

While this doesn't work:

```
(n < i) ? function() : return;
```

why does the shorthand if-statement doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` can't be used in an expression. Maybe you can try,

```
return (n < i) ? function() : undefined;
```

But that's only if you have one thing to do for each condition.

Comment: what should i use instead?

Comment: @razzak You can make it into `return (n < i) ? function() : undefined;`

Comment: nice, i like this solution +1